# What does "Got unknown event 17 ... continuing ..." mean with MPI

Tags: multithreading, events, mpi, icc, mvapich2

I am running an MPI job and am getting this warning message:

```
[comet-05-08.sdsc.edu:mpi_rank_10][async_thread] Got unknown event 17 ... continuing ...
```

I am compiling with icc (ICC) 15.0.2 20150121 using MVAPICH 2.1.

What does the message mean? Is it harmful?

Comment: Old posts point to this event: IBV_EVENT_CLIENT_REREGISTER a description is here: http://www.rdmamojo.com/2012/08/11/ibv_get_async_event/#IBV_EVENT_CLIENT_REREGISTER. Seems a system failure.

Answer (score 2):

From [this](http://mailman.cse.ohio-state.edu/pipermail/mvapich-discuss/2009-August/002475.html) mailing list:

> this error message is being printed by the asynchronous progress
>   thread because of receving an IBV_EVENT_CLIENT_REREGISTER event (event
>   #17).

It is suggested that you update to the latest version. The mail I linked to suggest MVAPICH2 1.4 (which is newer than yours), despite that the fact that the mail is from 2009.

---

The code, that *probably* generates that is:

```
switch (event.event_type) {
        ...

        break; 
    default:
        NEM_IB_ERR("Got unknown event %d ... continuing ...",
                event.event_type);
}
```

where you can find the full code [here](http://trac.mpich.org/projects/mpich/browser/src/mpid/ch3/channels/nemesis/nemesis/netmod/ib/ib_poll.c?rev=1cce5286a8c8e5ef5b7b911fd2c3722deae67b1b).

---

As indicated in the comment section:

**IBV_EVENT_CLIENT_REREGISTER**

> The SM requests that the client will reregister to all subscriptions
>   previously requested from this port, for example (but not limited to)
>   join a multicast group. This event may be generated when the SM
>   suffered from a failure, which caused it to lose his records or when
>   there is new SM in the subnet.
>
> This event will be generated by the device only if the bit that
>   indicates that client reregister is supported set in
>   `port_attr.port_cap_flags`.

[Source](http://www.rdmamojo.com/2012/08/11/ibv_get_async_event/#IBV_EVENT_CLIENT_REREGISTER)

---

I wouldn't be happy with that event, so if I were you, I would update. If the issue persists, I would contact the MVAPICH2 people.